# converting glyphs to SVGs

Tags: svg, web-applications, fonts, internationalization, typography

i'm building a website and wanted to display a bunch of international (pretty obscure) characters on the splashscreen. out of concern for platform-specific system fonts, instead of typing in those characters as text, i want to embed them as SVGs. does anyone know of an easy way to take the glyphs i'm seeing in my keynote / pdf and convert them to SVGs?

tried a bunch of things - converted keynote to pdf and used several online pdf->svg converters, but that misses some obscure characters and returns a misformatted svg. tried copying and pasting the text into figma and exporting as svg, but figma doesn't render more rare international fonts. i just want to take what  i'm seeing on my screen and make those SVGs.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that occurs to me is to open the fonts or drawings in an editor like Adobe Illustrator or Inskcape and edit them there and download them as svg

Comment: Using Inkscape, you must use the "Import with Poppler/Cairo" option on PDF imports.

Comment: @jose thanks, i did that and got an svg but inside of a <svg> tags the text "߷" + font name are still specified, but I'm trying to get pure bezier curves (since most fonts nowadays are vector-based, svg should work if i figure this out).

Comment: ah got it -- i selected the text and went to custom->export as svg, that gave me the path. thanks!